# How to deploy app to a select group of people?

Tags: android, google-play

A group of us are working on a game-related app that is applicable only to a specific city (it's not a game, but rather chat and information about the game in that city).

We're trying to figure out the best way to deploy it. I'd like to have it so anyone can request the app, but the moderators would identify the local players and approve them before they can install the app.

We don't want to make it completely public because then we'll be dealing with people that can't use the app. I don't want it to be completely private because then players in the area we don't know won't be able to find it.

Perhaps a link to the beta test on the Play Store from our group's website? Or could we use a closed test and collect the email address(es) from our website and add them manually?

We're open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

**Option 1** (recommended)

1. I would restrict the release to one country only
2. Then use open testing only with unlimited testers
3. Make it very clear in description and first screen of the app that this app for X city only
4. Make a landing page website to collect emails to invite people
5. send testing links to people

**Option 2**
Publish [private app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cregister-as-a-developer%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization), but this option is designed for organizations so it is not preferable but you can achieve what you want privately.